# Nativescript-vue simple select component like web

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I want to achieve below layout in `nativescript-vue`. Is there any plugin available through which I can design layout like this and it will work `same as web <select>` element? I just looked `ListPicker` component but its layout is different. Or how can I achieve a layout like this with `ListPicker` component?

[image]

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checkout [nativescript-drop-down](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-drop-down)

```
npm i --save nativescript-drop-down
```

Register UI component

```
Vue.registerElement("DropDown", () => require("nativescript-drop-down/drop-down").DropDown)
```

Now you should be able to use `DropDown` tag in your templates.

Comment: Angular / Vue are just wrappers around, for almost every UI plugin all you have to do is to register the element from the plugin and use it in your template

Comment: alright. thanks for suggestion. let me try to work out.